# Can not evoke watch command with non-integer time option

Tags: command-line, watch, w

I want to start the `w` command periodically, according to `man watch` the smallest possible time interval is 0.1.

I tried:

```
watch -n1 w        (works)
watch -n1.5 w      (does not work)
watch -n0.1 w      (does not work)
```

When I try to start the `watch` command with the n-option as non-integer, I get the error message:

```
watch: failed to parse argument: '0.1'
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What's the output of `watch --version`?

Comment: watch from procps-ng 3.3.9

Comment: Strange. Same as for me, and your examples work perfectly when copied and pasted.

Comment: Your locale is probably set to a value where the decimal point character is not a period character `"."` (confirm this by running `locale` in your shell). Try setting `LC_NUMERIC` in your environment to a locale that uses the period character. For example: `export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a locale problem. `watch` uses `strtod(3)`, which is locale-dependent, to convert the argument to `-n` to a `double`.

To fix the problem, you need to either specify the argument to `-n` with a different separator:

```
watch -n 0,1 w
```

Or change your locale to a setting where the period character is used for the decimal point:

```
export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
watch -n 0.1 w
```

A couple of references:

1. A relevant portion of the Linux manpage for `strtod`:

> A decimal number consists of a nonempty sequence of decimal digits possibly containing a radix character (decimal point, locale-dependent, usually '.')

2. You can review your current settings by running `locale` in your terminal:

   ```
   locale
   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
   LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
   ...
   ```
3. The source code in question can be reviewed at gitlab:

   https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/85fff468fa263cdd2ff1c0144579527c32333695/watch.c#L625

   https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/85fff468fa263cdd2ff1c0144579527c32333695/lib/strutils.c#L49

(edit 2017-09-07): updated gitlab links

Answer (score 3):

Just a complement to [zackse's fine answer](/a/193603).

There are two problems with:

```
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 watch -n 0.1 w
```

as a work around for the fact that `watch` expect numbers formatted in the user's convention while you expect it to be in the English format.

1. That doesn't work if `LC_ALL` is set. `LC_ALL` overrides all other locale settings including `LC_NUMERIC`. The work around would be to use:

   ```
   LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 watch -n 0.1 w
   ```

   but then it would make the second point below even worse
2. the command started by `watch` (in this case `w`) inherits that `LC_NUMERIC`. So instead of outputting its numbers in a format expected by the user, it will output it in the US English format.

Ideally here, we'd want to tell watch to run `w` every tenth of a second (regardless of the user's locale) without affecting the behaviour of the `w` command (which should always give an output understandable by the user in his own locale).

With the `yash` shell, you can do it with:

```
 watch -n "$((0.1))" w
```

`yash` is one of the 3 Bourne-like shells that support floating point arithmetics (the other ones being `zsh` and `ksh93`). It's the only one that does internationalisation properly though. `zsh` always uses `.` as the decimal mark, and `ksh93` honours the one from the locale event in its internal syntax.

For `yash`, `.` is the decimal mark for its arithmetic syntax, but it honours the locale's one upon input/output.

Another trick you can use here is to avoid inputting the decimal mark altogether by using scientific notation:

```
watch -n 1e-1 w
```

Or you can query the decimal mark from the locale:

```
m=$(locale decimal_point)
watch -n "0${m}1" w
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands `watch` and `w` have nothing to do with each other other than the first letter being equal. You cannot assume that a parameter for `w` is equally valid for `watch`. The `watch` command takes an integral number of seconds as the value for `-n`.

Incidentally, I've also looked at the [man page for `w`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/w) and I can't see any reference to a time period. I'm curious to know from where you got this information so that I can (hopefully) explain further.

UPDATE

It appears that you are actually referring to the timer for `watch`, not for `w`. I will update your question to match this new disclosure. Having finally discovered this, I cannot see anything wrong with `watch -n 0.1 w`.

Comment: I am now somehow confused, because all I know is that the watch-command executes periodically another command, regardless whether this command has a remark about usage of time in its man. I thought "watch <some_command>" is true for all commands without exceptions, like even "watch ls" though this one makes no sense it shows no error in the shell either.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred you are correct in that `watch` periodically executes another command. What I don't understand is why you think that the parameters for `w` should apply to `watch`. The command `watch ls` runs the `ls` command every two seconds, updating your screen with its current output.

Comment: I was told, that in the column idle of this commands output I can read for how long the keyboard has not been pressed. so I fought if i start "watch w"  i could watch the time increasing and then after pressing a key the time would drop to zero.  i tried first  just with one terminal and the idle time increased further even after pressing a key, second time i opened additionally a further terminal and when i pressed a key the idle time indeed changed, but not in a way as i espected,  so i fought maybe it is a delay-effect that is why i wanted to test watch with a very short time interval.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred `watch` uses integer second intervals. If I run `watch -d -n1 w` in one terminal and type keys on the keyboard in another I can see the _idle time_ dropping back down each time I type something.

Comment: me too, but what i do not get is , that when i press the key the time does not drop to 0 , it sometimes only goes a few seconds back, say from 20 to 17, and when it goes further back when i press several times in continuation a key.     i thought it would be simply:   one keypress = back to 0, but it is not like this, it has some strange logic how to go back of its own.

Comment: I still do not understand it when I compare it with the text in the man page of watch:       -n, --interval seconds
              Specify  update  interval.   The  command will not allow quicker
              than 0.1 second interval, in which the smaller values  are  con‐
              verted.     ...........also in another question someone posts an non integer value for watch -n .

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred you said this time was in the man page for `w`. Not for `watch`.